# how to write select query for the following criteria

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables in DB

- profilePermission=>columns(profileid,permissionid,profilename)
- Permissions=>columns(permissionid,permissionname)

Each profile can have multiple permissions. (e.g) profile1 can have permission1,permission2,permission3 and profile2 can have permission3,permission2

I want to write a query that fetches the count of profileid which has permissions.permissionname= permission1 and permissions.permissionname !=permission2 and vice versa.

I tried something like this

```
select profileid  
from  CrmProfilePermissions 
join CrmPermissions on CrmProfilePermissions.permissionid=CrmPermissions.permissionid 
where name in ('permission1') and name not in('permission2') 
group by (profileid).
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: In your where condition what is the need for `name not in('permission2')` since there is already `name in ('permission1')`. These 2 conditions are mutually exclusive. Also instead of adding this in where condition you can add this as the part of join `inner join CrmPermissions on CrmProfilePermissions.permissionid=CrmPermissions.permissionid and CrmPermissions.name in ('permission1')`

Comment: @PrabuM . . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

you have a missing aggregation function `count()`

```
select profileid, count(1) as cnt
from CrmProfilePermissions 
join CrmPermissions on CrmProfilePermissions.permissionid=CrmPermissions.permissionid 
where name in ('permission1') and name not in('permission2') 
group by (profileid)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct selectquery

it is

```
select profileid  from  CrmProfilePermissions
join CrmPermissions on CrmProfilePermissions.permissionid=CrmPermissions.permissionid
where  name in ('permission1','permission2')
group by (profileid)
having count(distinct name)=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two levels of aggregation:

```
select has_permission1, has_permission2, count(*),
       min(profileid), max(profileid)  -- I just include these as examples
from (select pp.profileid,
             max(case when p.name = 'permission1' then 1 else 0 end) as has_permission1,
             max(case when p.name = 'permission2' then 1 else 0 end) as has_permission2
      from CrmProfilePermissions pp join
           CrmPermissions p
           on pp.permissionid = p.permissionid
      group by pp.profileid
     ) p
group by has_permission1, has_permission2;
```